# Word for someone who collects dice

Tags: single-word-requests

I collect game dice as a hobby. What is a word for someone who collects dice?

Comment: seems to be "dice collector"

Comment: "D&D player" :-)

Comment: @Manu Are they 'open' dice or 'closed' dice? :p

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Edited:
  The official word is "dice collector". This is taken from a [dice collecting site:](http://dicemaniacsclub.multiply.com/)

> You'll be able to chat to fellow dice collectors from all over the world,

There's also the [Dice Collector Forum](http://dicecollector.com/forums/index.php?topic=2.0), for discussing dice collecting.

Comment: I believe this refers to a personal who *physically* collects dice, *as part of the game of Craps*, rather than someone who collects dice *as a hobby*.

Comment: surely you're mistaking the OP's meaning of "collects" here ! He means *as a hobby* , and not *recover*

Comment: Oh, shucks! All that trouble for nothing!

Answer (score 12):

If you mean what is the word that has the same relation to *game dice collection* as *philately* to *stamp collection*?

Then, I don't think there is already one (also note: while dictionaries define philately as *collection and study of stamps*, according to encyclopedias stamp collecting is not the same as philately, which is the study of stamps, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stamp_collecting#Collecting) and [here](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/455889/philately)).

If you want to be inventive you could attempt to coin:

***philastragaly***
*phil-* "loving" + *astragaloi* "knucklebones"

EDIT:
This form was chosen due to etymology of philately

> The word "philately" is the English version of the French word "philatélie", coined by Georges Herpin in 1864. Herpin stated that stamps had been collected and studied for the previous six or seven years and a better name was required for the new hobby than *timbromanie*, which was disliked. He took the Greek root word *phil* or *philo*, meaning an attraction or affinity for something, and *ateleia*, meaning "exempt from duties and taxes" to form "philatelie". The introduction of postage stamps meant that the receipt of letters was now free of charge, whereas before stamps it was normal for postal charges to be paid by the recipient of a letter.
>
> The alternative terms "timbromania", "timbrophily" and "timbrology" gradually fell out of use as philately gained acceptance during the 1860s.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to have "philastragaly" or "philastragale", on the pattern of "philanthropy" or "misanthrope" (not "philanthropoi", "misanthropoi", even though "men" is "anthropoi" in Greek).

Comment: My mistake. You see I'm french and in French "philatélie" means stamp collecting, "numismatie" means coin collecting and so on. I only recently (10 minutes ago) learned that in english those words mean "the study of _"

Comment: @psmears, I've put in your suggested form of *philastragaly*

Comment: It seems that, even in French, the word means "study of _" as well as "collecting _"

Comment: I think lots of English speakers also believe philately means stamp collecting (and if lots of English speakers believe it, who's to say they're wrong?).

Comment: -1 for *"philately is not stamp collection"*. That must be one of the most pedantic statements I've ever seen on ELU.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I have changed the wording in attempt to be even more pedantic ;) (and also more objective)

Comment: @Unreason: haha. Well I suppose if you're going to be pedantic it's always a good idea to have references to back up your position! But by and large I tend to side with Humpty-Dumpty on such questions. A word primarily means what most people *think* it means, even if there is solid evidence to show that they are misusing it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I agree - that's why I changed the wording. I think it is objective to say what is the common use and what is more specialized and that neither should be ignored. The word means what most people (of a certain group) think it means. If such group is equal to whole nation you have clear common meaning. If such group is some subculture the meaning is not necessarily lost, even if it contradicts the majority and even if the group is comparatively small.

Answer (score 9):

Following "coin collector", "stamp collector", and so on, the collector of dice should be known as a "die collector".

Comment: +1 for the use of "die" as the singular to follow "coin" and "stamp".

Answer (score 5):

The Romans had actual dice, rather than the Greek knucklebones: the word was *alea*, as in  Caesar's "*Alea iacta est*".  Wouldn't **aleaphile** be easier to pronounce?

Answer (score 4):

going with Unreason may I propose **astragaloiphile**

and as psmears suggested (going by the "anthromorphoi" precedent) - **astragalophile**

Comment: I think "astragalophile" would work slightly better - it's "anthropophage" not "anthropoiphage" ("men" is "anthropoi").

Comment: I used the reverse pattern to mimic philately (which, btw, has interesting etymology)

Comment: @psmears the thought occurred to me :) thanks for the "anthropoi" precedent - I'll include it in the edited answer
@Unreason oh that's why you ordered it like that - nice suggestion btw - I'm just a dwarf standing on the shoulder of giants :)

Answer (score 2):

A tongue-in-cheek term:

Someone who collects dice is a *cubist*.

Comment: Nearly funny, except for all those non-cubic polyhedra they use for dice with other than 6 sides :)

Comment: @NickWiggill, details, details...

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @tchrist Mine may not be *the* answer, but it's certainly *an* answer. The OP doesn't specify the context, and a tongue-in-cheek term may be helpful, if not to the OP then perhaps to a future reader. The question asks for a term, and I offered one. I'm not asking for clarification -- I don't understand why you think this should be a comment.

Comment: Because it’s meant to be humor, not real.

Comment: @tchrist It's meant to be a humorous term, but I didn't offer this answer simply as a joke. The set of amusing answer and the set of "real" answers do occasionally intersect.

Answer (score 1):

Philocubist is a person who loves dice games but not specifically a collector, and tesserarian is "of, like or pertaining to dice games" but even though dice games pre-date historical records, there is not a known term used by present-day collectors

Answer (score -1):

You collect dice with a rake at a craps table (and other less popular games).  A more invented term for a die collector would be a **raker**.